# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, html, sandbox

I'm trying to change style inside an iframe, I gave to the iframe the `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"` attribute but I still get 'Blocked a frame with origin' what more can be the issue ?

```
<iframe
  height="100%"
  sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
  src={formLink}
  onLoad={event => {
    console.log('event', event, event.target);
    const iframeEle = event.target;
    const iframeEleDocument = (iframeEle.contentWindow || iframeEle.contentDocument);
    console.log('iframeEleDocument', iframeEleDocument);
    debugger;
    iframeEleDocument.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }}
/>
```

Comment: different ports?

Comment: and if the ports are different how can I handle it ?

Comment: postMessage since different ports are seen as different domains.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184505/sandboxing-iframe-and-allow-same-origin

Comment: thanks for your comments, but I don't have access to the url that is implemented in the iframe src.

Comment: Then you cannot change it's contents through cross-origin js

Comment: thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sandboxing controls what the iframe (resp. the document that is loaded inside it) can do, but it does not disable the _Same Origin Policy_.

Answer (score 0):

I think the`postMessage` is the security way to do that.  You can set an event function in your iframe by using `postMessage`, and you can do what you wanna do there.

GitHub has many goods about the postMessage, and you can do it conveniently.