# SharedArrayBuffer in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sharedarraybuffer

So SharedArrayBuffer was recently [limited to Cross-origin isolated pages](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/) as a security fix.

We have a tool that depends on SharedArrayBuffer, I reworked it to *work again* by moving it to a barebones page stripped of all other site UI and what not and sending the following headers:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

Trying to load it in an iframe of the full-fledged site gives me the console errors `SharedArrayBuffer will require cross-origin isolation as of M92` followed by `ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined` - same as I was getting before I cross origin isolated the tool on the minimal page itself.

The page I'm trying to include the iframe in is *not* cross-origin isolated. It would be very difficult if not impossible to do so. I don't need to talk to the iframe from the parent page at all, it's just a convenience/stylistic thing. The current solution on production right now is just to link users to the minimal cross origin tool page in a new window, but that's pretty awkward.

What I'm hoping is that there is some combination of iframe [sandbox attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) or something that would make this work? I fought with this for a couple hours.

This may not be doable for all I know.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` tokens in the iframe's `sandbox` attribute:

```html
<iframe src="…" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here are some relevant resources on the topic:

- [Sandboxing, IFrame, and allow-same-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184505/sandboxing-iframe-and-allow-same-origin) (StackOverflow question)
- [Securing an iframe thanks to the sandbox attribute](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2015/07/securing-iframe-sandbox-attribute/)
- [`<iframe>`: The Inline Frame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe?retiredLocale=uk#attr-sandbox) (MDN docs), – don't miss the **Note** about security in the attribute's description.

---

Try the above first, and if it didn't help with the `SharedArrayBuffer` problem you have, then things are a bit more complex.

Proper cross-origin requires explicit headers from the subresources (the `<iframe>` has to send headers), which is a big problem when the subresources are third-party and out of control. To mitigate this problem, there is a [proposal `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: credentialles`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/coep-credentialless-origin-trial/).

However, there's a catch: [it doesn't change how `<iframe>` works](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/coep-credentialless-origin-trial/#can-i-also-load-cross-origin-iframes-without-special-headers-under-a-credentialless-environment) (bummer, this is exactly what's needed!). There's [a discussion about anonymous iframes](https://github.com/camillelamy/explainers/blob/main/anonymous_iframes.md), that would solve this issue, but it is not resolved yet, so I'm wouldn't hold my breath here.

So, the only option that's left is to [**delay this change in Chrome behavior**](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial) (which can be done before Chrome 103):

> 1. [Request a token](https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/303992974847508481) for your origin.
> 2. Add the token to your pages. There are two ways to do that:
>
>    - Add a `<meta>` tag to the head of each page. For example, this may look something like: `<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="TOKEN_GOES_HERE">`
>    - If you can configure your server, you can also add the token using an `Origin-Trial` HTTP header. The resulting response header should look something like: `Origin-Trial: TOKEN_GOES_HERE`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this option is a solution in your case, but maybe it can help you find a complete solution.
This [blogpost](https://dev.to/stefnotch/enabling-coop-coep-without-touching-the-server-2d3n) describes enabling SharedArrayBuffer via header modification in ServiceWorker. It works in the following order:

1. When the page is loaded for the first time, a Service worker is registered
2. The page is reloaded
3. SharedArrayBuffer becomes available because ServiceWorker controls all CORS headers for all requests

Service Worker modifies all requests by adding CORS/COEP headers (The example is taken from the mentioned blogpost):

```js
self.addEventListener("install", function() {
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  if (event.request.cache === "only-if-cached" && event.request.mode !== "same-origin") {
    return;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request)
    .then(function(response) {
      // It seems like we only need to set the headers for index.html
      // If you want to be on the safe side, comment this out
      // if (!response.url.includes("index.html")) return response;

      const newHeaders = new Headers(response.headers);
      newHeaders.set("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
      newHeaders.set("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");

      const moddedResponse = new Response(response.body, {
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText,
        headers: newHeaders,
      });

      return moddedResponse;
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
      console.error(e);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, this just alleviates the need to set the headers which isn't a problem I have. I am perfectly able to set the headers server side. I already have the tool itself working on a page with the headers set and nothing else. The problem is the headers break everything on the normal site, namely loading JS from a CDN. Reworking the entire site and maintaining the changes for this tool an option. This is why I wanted to load the minimal working tool in an iframe - I'm getting the sense that it isn't possible but I'm not sure why such a restriction would exist.

Comment: Then, as far as I know, there is currently no way to use a Shared Array Buffer inside an iframe.
This has already been discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322834/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-cross-origin-isolated-iframe-inside-a-normal-page/69363428